# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object When accessing ViewModel list through controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, viewmodel

So my View Model is not giving my CSV file's information to the view correctly. I have already placed a break point and the List "Stocks" fills up nicely and I can even see all the values in `public IEnumerable<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }` However the var, ViewModel is null when I got to my controller? Any suggestions?
Here is the View Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using StockApp.Models;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using CsvHelper;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;


namespace StockApp.ViewModels.StockInfo
{
    public class StockInfoViewModel
    {
        public StockInfoViewModel()
        {
            List<Stock> Stocks = new List<Stock>();

            string file ="../StockApp/App_Data/companylist.csv";
            using(var reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {


                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(',');
                    Stocks.Add(new Stock { Name = values[1], Symbol = values[0] });
                }
            }

        }
        public IEnumerable<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And Here is the Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using StockApp.Models;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using CsvHelper;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace StockApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult StockInfo()
        {
            var ViewModel = new ViewModels.StockInfo.StockInfoViewModel().Stocks;

            return View(ViewModel);
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public IActionResult About()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

The Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StockApp.Models
{
    public class StockNamesModel
    {
        public List<Stock> Stocks {get; set;}

    }

    public class Stock 
    {
        public string Symbol{get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
    }


}
```

Last but not least the Razor Code

```
@model StockApp.ViewModels.StockInfo.StockInfoViewModel
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h1>Our Advanced Algorithims To Buy and Sell These Stocks</h1>

<table class="table table-dark">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var stock in Model.Stocks)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@stock.Symbol</td>
                <td>@stock.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would be apreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change 2 things in your `ViewModel`

*ViewModel*

- Remove `List<Stock>` and assign directly, which looks like `Stocks = new List<Stock>();`
- `IEnumerable<Stock>` to `List<Stock>` which becomes  `public List<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }`

Reason for *null*:

`List<Stock> Stocks` scope is within the constructor and `IEnumerable<Stocks>` is not tracking `List<Stock> Stocks`

And from your Controller you are trying to access the IEnumerable which is not assigned anything in the first place

**Updated Code:**

```
public class StockInfoViewModel
{
    public StockInfoViewModel()
    {
        Stocks = new List<Stock>();

        string file ="../StockApp/App_Data/companylist.csv";
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(file))
        {


            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');
                Stocks.Add(new Stock { Name = values[1], Symbol = values[0] });
            }
        }

    }
    public List<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Stocks` property of an `StockInfoViewModel` instance is not assigned. You set the intental variable `Stocks` within the constructor.

You need to replace the line

```
List<Stock> Stocks = new List<Stock>();
```

with

```
this.Stocks = new List<Stock>();
```

Comment: Thanks, just had to switch the IEnumerator with a public list, and it works nicely.